# < was unexpected at this time (Batch script)

Tags: batch-file, command-line, parameters

I am a beginner batch/bash script writer and having a bit of trouble with this code. The rest of the code works perfectly fine it is just the first parameter section that is being troublesome. Any help/advice would be gratefully received. Here is my code:

```
@echo off

:commandline

if [%1]==[] (
    echo No data entered. Please continue as normal.
    goto :welcome 
)

IF NOT %3 == "" (  
    echo.
    echo Too many parameters given... 
    goto :welcome  
)

IF EXIST %2 (  
    xcopy %2 bak_%2
    %2 notepad
    goto :eof
    exit. 
)

:welcome

echo. 
echo **********************************
echo   Welcome to the Backup Program!!  
echo **********************************
echo. 

set /p answer=Please enter your name: 
echo. 
echo Hello %answer% please make a selection from the menu below 
echo. 

:start 

echo Option 1 - Backup and Edit
echo Option 2 - Create a Batch File
echo Option 3 - Quit
echo. 
choice /C:321


IF errorlevel 3 goto option1
IF errorlevel 2 goto option2
IF errorlevel 1 goto option3

:option1

echo. 
set /p file=Please type in the name of the file: 


if %file% == quit (
    echo.
    echo The program will now close. 
        pause
        Exit
    )

        if %file% == Quit (
            echo. 
            echo The program will now close. 
                pause
                Exit
            )

                IF NOT EXIST %file% goto :option1
                    echo.
                    copy %file% bak_%file% 
                    %file% notepad 

                        pause
                        echo. 
                        goto :start 

:option2

echo > %file%.bat
echo file=%file% > %file%.bat 
echo IF EXIST %file% ( >> %file%.bat 
echo    copy %file% bak_%file% >> %file%.bat 
echo    %file% notepad >> %file%.bat 
echo ) else ( >> %file%.bat 
echo    echo .> %file% >> %file%.bat 
echo    %file% notepad >> %file%.bat 
echo ) >> %file%.bat

goto :eof

:option3

goto :eof 

:eof

echo Thanks for using the Backup Program. 
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the exact way you are calling the script?

I believe the problem is in the line `IF NOT %3 == "" (`.  It looks like you are trying to verify that the third parameter is empty.  I'm guessing you are calling the script by doing something like this: `script.bat parm1 parm2 < some_file`.  I think it is seeing the `<` as the third parameter so it's trying to execute `IF NOT < == ""` which is invalid syntax.  Putting double quotes around the `%3` should fix that part.  I'm not sure if that will fix the fact that it is treating the `<` as a parameter, though.

Comment: Hey. What i want that to do is if there is a 3rd parameter given it displays an error message stating "too many parameters". I used syntax for if not %3 = empty.

I'm calling Batch.bat hello - am i right in thinking this should run?

and if i were to call Batch.bat hello hi then the error message should display?

Comment: I figured that was the intent.  Still, `IF NOT "%3" == "" (` is the way that I would test for it being empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I see when I read your script.  Use my answer as a debugging guide that can help you make your script run the way you wanted it.

`IF NOT %3 == "" (` should be `IF NOT "%3" == "" (`

That same section should `goto :eof`?

The `exit.` in the `IF EXIST %2` will never get executed, and if it was meant as exit, should not have a period. Just delete?

All the places where you have `%file% notepad` (and similar) do not make sense to me. Should they be `notepad %file%` to edit the file in notepad?

In `option2:` the line `echo > %file%.bat` does nothing since the following line will create the file from scratch again.